# How to extract data from a file with only specified folder as argument in Python?

Tags: python, metadata, data-extraction

so I'm working with a file directory for which I need to write a function that, when given arguments that lead to a folder in that directory, can extract metadata from the first and last file in that folder. I have written a function that extracts metadata when given a file path to a single file but I also need one that does this without the file being a specified endpoint.

Can anyone help me? I don't know how to get the function to go into the specified folder and read specific files without the files being arguments. Does that make sense? Sorry if it doesn't. Thanks.

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: What makes a file the "last file" in a directory? Is it A to Z?

Comment: Please post your code, and also try to explain what you mean by metadata. You seem to say it comes from a file and then also that it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

A bit sketchy (not a working code!) but I hope you get the idea

```
import os

def extract_metadata(file_path):
    pass

def full_path(folder_path, fname):
    return os.path.join(folder_path, fname)

def folder_metadata(folder_path):
    file_names = os.listdirt(folder_path)
    file1 = full_path(select_first(file_names))
    file2 = full_path(select_last(file_names))
    return extract_metadata(file1), extract_metadata(file2)
```